# Increment date in date field

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with 365 records,this table also have one date column with null value.I want to insert date in all the rows with increment of 1 day with current date.
Ex: current date in 1st column and in 2nd column it should be next day's and so on...difference should be of 24hrs between all the date records.

Comment: So, have you read about `UPDATE` and/or `DATEADD`? This is really a trivial operation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this update query:

```
UPDATE tbl SET Col2 = DATEADD(d, 1, Col1)
```

Comment: after running this query message box shows 364 rows affected and table still showing null result for all rows in date column.

Comment: `364 rows affected` then you have 364 rows in your table. Show your table creation and insertion script.

Answer (score 0):

A stored routine with a cursor inside should do the job:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `insert_ascending_dates` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `insert_ascending_dates`()
BEGIN

declare done int default false;
declare t_id int;
declare c cursor for select [id] from [table];
declare continue handler for not found set done = true;

set @dte = date();
set @strSql = 'update [table] set [date] = ? where [id] = ?';
prepare stmt from @strSql;

open c;
read_loop: loop
  fetch c into t_id;
  if done then
    leave read_loop;
  end if;
  set @tId = t_id;
  execute stmt using @dte, @tId;
  set @dte = date_add(@dte, interval 1 day);
end loop;
close c;

deallocate prepare stmt;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

After creating the routine, you'll need to call it as follows:

```
call insert_ascending_dates();
```

Comment: Strange, this question came up when I searched for "mysql answers:0". I didn't think to look at the tag. Will make sure to do so next time.